# Oracle Cloud Instance internet connection is very slow

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am setting up a few compute instances on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. The speed is ok but the internet connection (both ingress and egress) is very slow. It happens to all the instances.
Even worse, if I set the instances behind Cloudflare, it is much slower compared to connecting directly to the instances. Does anyone happen to have the same experience?

Comment: Not a question for this site. Try here - https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing good!!
I see that the internet network for you VM is slow, I guess it’s the default speed that you are getting as when we use a free tier VM in OCI the max throughput of network bandwidth is 50mbps, please refer this to get more details : https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/FreeTier/resourceref.htm#compute
Adding on, you can refer this for network bandwidth for different OCI VM sizes : https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/References/computeshapes.htm
you can even check if there is any firewall setup or VPN (excluding cloudflare) through which you are accessing the internet which could impact the network connection.

Thanks,
Hemanth.

Comment: No I am a paid user. My instances have 16 cores each. The speed limit for them is Gbs not Mbs. I am having a lot of troubles with OCI recently.

Comment: @JohnBui - it's probably best to open a service request and have Cloud Ops to analyze it then